# "has_many through" association doesn't work when using a custom ActiveRecord::Type (binary) column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I've created the following **ActiveRecord type** and while `has_many` associations work well, `has_many :through` don't:

```rb
# app/types/uuid_type.rb
class UuidType < ActiveRecord::Type::Binary
  def serialize(value)
    super(cast_to_uuid(value)&.raw)
  end

  def deserialize(value)
    cast_to_uuid(super(value)).to_s
  end

  def cast_value(value)
    cast_to_uuid(value).to_s
  end

  private

  def cast_to_uuid(value)
    return if value.nil?

    case value.size
    when 16 then UUIDTools::UUID.parse_raw(value) # From `uuidtools` gem
    when 36 then UUIDTools::UUID.parse(value)     # From `uuidtools` gem
    end
  end
end
```

```rb
# app/models/token.rb
class Token < ActiveRecord::Base
  attribute :id, UuidType.new, default: SecureRandom.uuid

  has_many :token_users
  has_many :users, through: :token_users
end
```

(I've also written an entire [code to replicate the issue](https://gist.github.com/lucascaton/3ba870fda1fcde9f8807a934896b4796)).

---

The SQL `where` clause generated for `has_many` is similar to the following and works perfectly:

```sql
WHERE column = x'4e254953bcdb4793a485ac04131565a7'
```

While the one generated for `has_many :through` does not work:

```sql
WHERE column = '4e254953-bcdb-4793-a485-ac04131565a7'
```

It doesn't return any error, but also **doesn't return any results**.

The problem is that the second one (`has_many :through`) doesn't include the `x` prefix and also doesn't remove the hyphens (If I manually do that, it solves the issue).

I was able to replicate the issue with both **MySQL** and **SQlite** and both **Rails 5** and **6**.

Why does the `has_many :through` relationship not produce the same SQL for a binary type? And how can you get it working so that it does?

Comment: Why you using custom AR type to create `uuid` instead of using mysql `uuid` type column?

Comment: @MartinZinovsky As opposed to PostgreSQL, I think MySQL doesn't have a `uuid` type :)
Anyway, I wouldn't be able to change it now as this table has lots of records already and changing it would break other things. Thanks.

Comment: FYI [`Mysql 8.0 has UUID support`](https://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-8-0-uuid-support/)

Comment: Thanks, @MartinZinovsky! The column type used in the example from the link you sent is `binary`. That's what I'm using already :)
But Rails doesn't serialise/deserialise it out of the box yet, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that it was a Rails bug.

I've submitted [an issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/35839)  on the official repo and they've fixed it:

https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/36847

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it'll help, but go to config/initializers/type.rb and add

```
ActiveRecord::Type.register(:token_users, UuidType)
```

Comment: Based on [`ActiveRecord::Type.register docs`](https://rubydocs.org/d/rails-5-1-7-rc1/classes/ActiveRecord/Type.html#method-c-register) first argument should be `type_name` but you have table name here

Comment: I don't think that's the problem, otherwise `has_many` (without `:through`) wouldn't work.

Comment: I've just tested, it didn't work indeed. Thanks anyway.